# How to make copies of an AST branch in Babel plugin?

Tags: babeljs

Is there a clean way to make a copy/clone/duplicate of an AST subtree/branch in a Babel plugin? For example, lets say I start with a snippet like:

```
  x = <Big, complicated AST>;
```

and I want to transform it to something like:

```
  if( phase of moon )
    x = <Big, complicated AST with raspberry tweaks>;
  else
    x = <Big, complicated AST with yellow tweaks>;
```

I know that making copies of whole subtrees has the potential to exponentially blow-up the code size, but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel's `types` property from the plugin API has `cloneNode`:

```
module.exports = function({ types: t }) {

  return {
    visitor: {
      SomeNode(path) {
        const newNode = t.cloneNode(path.node);
      }
    }
  }
};
```